# Problems saving excel documents with my custom wsgidav server

Tags: excel, webdav, wsgidav

I implemented my custom webdav server using the python package wsgidav to connect with a private cloud file storage but I'm having problems saving excel files.
When I open an excel file it's in "Protected view" and when I press "Enable edition" the file open again for edition.
But when I want to save the file excel says this:
[image]

but there aren't changes from another user because I'm the only one.

I think that the issue is related with this, [WebDAV - Microsoft Excel 2016 not able to save back changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138554/webdav-microsoft-excel-2016-not-able-to-save-back-changes) , but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in Excel if the etag changes after clicking to edit - because some systems generate fresh etags everytime a GET is issued this can occur - use Fiddler to find out whether the etag is staying consistent.